# Ab testing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ab-testing

I am trying to check two versions of one page on wordpress website via ab testing.
In the variant I will be changing the order of the elements and adding new ones and changing existing ones.
Which plugin (preferebly free one, or affordable) is suitable for this?
Can't seem to find anything helpful.

Tried vwo platform - couldn't add the functionality that I wanted for the variant..

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13468470?hl=en 
maybe GA?